# How to create a SSH connection between Ansible and Jenkins containers

Tags: networking, docker, ansible, jenkins, containers

I'm new to Jenkins.

My goal is to create a **Jenkins job\pipeline that will activate a group of ansible's playbook files** - which will create
a long installation of my tested product.

I build **2 containers** in Docker desktop (Windows): *Ansible* and *Jenkins*.

Below Ansible docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  ansible:
    container_name: ansible
    hostname: ansible
    image: ansible
    volumes:
      - ~/product/ansible:/ansible
    working_dir: /ansible
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    dns:
      - 200.20.0.20
    networks:
    - network

networks:
  network:
    external: true
```

Below Jenkins docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
    - ~/r10_core/jenkins:/jenkins
    networks:
    - network

networks:
  network:
    external: true
```

Ansible and Jenkins are on the same Network Id. So, `ping` command is working from *Ansible* to *Jenkins* and vis versa. Both containers have access to Internet.

I set username and password *admin* | *admin* and installed the following plugins in *Jenkins* container through *Jenkins site > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins*:

- **Ansible plugin**
- **SSH**
- **Publish by SSH**

I checked the SSH services in both machines.

*Ansible:*

```sh
[root@ansible ansible]# ssh 172.20.0.2
ssh: connect to host 172.20.0.2 port 22: Connection refused
[root@ansible ansible]# service --status-all
bash: service: command not found
[root@ansible ansible]# systemd
bash: systemd: command not found
[root@ansible ansible]# systemctl
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
[root@ansible ansible]#
```

*Jenkins:*

```sh
root@jenkins:/# ssh 172.20.0.3
ssh: connect to host 172.20.0.3 port 22: Connection refused
root@jenkins:/# service --status-all
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
root@jenkins:/#
```

I got a `Connection refused` also when trying to connect to the machines themselves

a) What should I configure in the Ansible container in order SSH to be active?
b) What should I configure in the Jenkins container in order SSH to be active?
c) What should I configure in each container in order them talk each other through SSH (*i.e* port 22)?

Comment: I think this question should be rephrased. It's not clear what you are actually *trying to do*, here. "Separate Containers" is **one** problem, while creating or autogenerating an `ansible-playbook` or `ansible` command is very different. (TLDR; Jobs may also intra-communicate to some extent - more with "a bit of imagination")

Comment: @RVT thanks for you response. I focused the question to one problem - SSH connection between Ansible and Jenkins containers

Comment: You misunderstood the concept of containers. What you want are VMs.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The principle in containers is that each container performs only one service and in a good way. I want the Jenkins service to consume an Ansible service. Is it possible? If so, you can indicate this in response to the post, if not - please clarify your position as to why such a definition is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Hiddai... there's no such thing as a "Jenkins container," unless you're talking about containers managed by Jenkins, under Docker or another container provider. SSH connections between one host and another are a pretty well understood problem (hint: look at ssh-agent and ssh keys)